# React native push notification local notification not displayed on real devices

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-push-notification

I was following the guide of https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification to enable cloud messaging functionalities in the app. Under the hood, I'm using react-native-firebase. During the development, I had to trigger a local notification based on the cloud message received from the custom backend server.

However, the app is not popping up any local notification in the system tray but I could see the app is receiving the notification and updating the data in the background. In the docs, I have seen that we need to create a channel to pop up notifications in the tray. I created the channel and called local notification. Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Please check the code below to trigger the notification based on a cloud remote message.

**"I can receive a notification on the background but there is no notification displayed to the user in the tray"**

```
    //Background handler
    messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
      //Trigger a local notification when app is offline
      LocalNotification(remoteMessage["data"]["id"]);
      this.updateData();
    });
```

And the local notification is triggered from the file.

```
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification'

export const LocalNotification = (data) => {
  console.log("Triggering a local notif")
  
  PushNotification.createChannel({
      channelId: "mychannel", // (required)
      channelName: "My channel", // (required)
      vibrate: true,
  }, (created) => {
    PushNotification.localNotification({
      channelId: "mychannel",
      autoCancel: true,
      bigText: data,
      subText: 'Notification',
      title: 'New notification received',
      message: `Notif ID: ${data}`,
      vibrate: true,
      vibration: 300,
      playSound: true,
      soundName: 'default',
      ignoreInForeground: false,
      importance:'high',
      invokeApp:true,
      allowWhileIdle: true,
      priority:'high',
      visibility:'public'
    })
  })
}
```

kindly comment below for any extra information. Thank you!

Comment: The same happens to me. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Creating a channel is the solution. Also make sure you are setting priority high to android from the backend